# How can I importrange from mulitple URL

Tags: google-sheets

Basing on this [tutorial](https://www.lido.app/tutorials/import-multiple-sheets-with-importrange-in-google-sheets)

I have tried to importrange from multiple spreadsheet, but it won't work.
I'm trying to use:

```
={importrange(url,range1);importrange(url,range2)}
```

But I always get only the import from the URL I put int the first `importrange` function

If I import them separatly with:

```
=importrange("url","data_range")
```

It works!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: both the sheets are loading; check the rows 1001+ for sheet2 results... use query OR filter to null out the blank rows & see the whole data at one spot.

Comment: Now that I have edit and correct the question, anyway for somebody to delete the -1 evaluation on it, because it still there, and I found it really unfair !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just importing the 1000 blank row. SO the second sheet appear at line 1001

here is the formula I found using query to clean my work :

`=QUERY({importrange(url,range1);importrange(url,range2)}, "Select * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")`
know it's perfectly doing the job !